# How to get workspace (document) path on Linux and Windows using commandline?

Tags: shell

I have a script which is copy the file source to user workspace when run the script. here i need to get current user workspace from commandline. Can you help me how to get it on both Windows and Linux

Thanks in advance - sri

Comment: "User workspace" does not have a definition on either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by Workspace? If you mean the user's home directory, you can get this via the environment variable `$HOME` on Linux, and I think the equivalent on Windows would be `%HOMESHARE%` (not totally sure about the last one, because I am on a Domain computer with roaming profiles right now, and I'm not sure if there is any special setup on it.